# How much health do Bastet's cats have?

Tags: smite

Bastet's ult spawns kitties. What is the health of these cats ?

How do they scale ?

How much damage do they do ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't be certain about their health as Bastet was recently reworked and their HP is no longer on the tooltip(it shows protections instead), so it may be wrong. The other information is current, however.

**Damage:** 25/35/45/55/65 (+20% of your physical power) + 20% slow

**Protections:** 20/30/40/50/60 (no scaling)

**Health:** 650/700/750/800/850. (no scaling)

sources:
[Most current stats (minus hp)](http://smite.gamepedia.com/Bastet) and [An outdated guide that has the old tooltip](http://2p.com/230262_1/Bastet-Guide.htm)